# glob.iglob Remove path from filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get the most recent file added to a directory using python 2.7 `os` and `glob` modules.

```
import os
import glob

path = "files/"
newestFile = max(glob.iglob(path + '*.txt'), key=os.path.getctime)

print newestFile
```

When I print the `newestFile` variable I get the path included i.e.

> files\file.txt

I just want the `filename` but my `.txt` file and `.py` script are not in the same directory. The text file is one directory down under the files directory. How do I refer to the directory and get the newest `.txt` file added to that directory.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you really want? just the filename or filename of file stored in some other directory ? is `file.txt` not the expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR Sorry. The expected output is file.txt but what I am getting is files\file.txt. The suggestion by Padraic Cunningham did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.basename` to just get the filename:

```
newestFile = os.path.basename(max(glob.iglob(path + '*.txt'), key=os.path.getctime))
```

`os.path.getctime` is going to need the full path so one way or another you would have to use the full path.

Comment: that did the job. Thanks. Appreciate it.